# Dynamic regex pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some code that matches a certain number of digits after a decimal. Currently, I have the following:

```
var input = getValueFromUser();
var count = getCount();
var x = Number(input.toString().match(/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,1})?/));
alert(x);
```

This approach always gets the first digit after the decimal. However, I want to replace the 1 in the regex with the value in `count`. How do I do that? I tried the following:

```
var pattern = '/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,' + count + '})?/';
var x = Number(input.toString().match(pattern));
```

However, now, I always get `0` for `x`.

Comment: You have to use `Regexp` object if you want to use dynamic patterns

Comment: BTW, isn't `\D` the same as `^\d`?

Answer (score 6):

You have to use [`Regexp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object if you want to use dynamically built patterns:

```
var re = new RegExp('^\\d+(?:\\.\\d{0,' + count + '})?');
```

Comment: Note that the backslashes in the string need to be escaped (unlike backslashes in a regex literal).

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
var pattern = '^\\d+(?:\\.\\d{0,' + '5' + '})?',
    reg=new RegExp(pattern),
    x = Number(input.toString().match(reg));
```

Comment: Don't include the `/` at the beginning and end of the regex pattern if supplying it as a string - that's for regex literals only. Also if the pattern is in a string you need to escape the backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

`` mask: new RegExp(`^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,${maxLength}}$`) ``

its work for me

Answer (score 0):

```
var alien = 'ajay'+' $%';
var all=new RegExp(`${alien}`)
```